# Convert anaconda package to pypi package

Tags: python, conda

I built an anaconda package called pycadet from sources with external dependencies like sundials. Everything works fine within conda . However, I cannot use that package in an environment which is built solely on PyPi repo. Is it somehow possible to convert an anaconda package to a PyPi package without building everything by hand again.

Comment: In the general case no, because Conda lets you pull in libraries etc which `pip` cannot do.